# Solve equation with array gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra

I have

$$
\left|
\begin{array}{rrr}
 x &   -2   & 3x-6  \\
           -x &   5  &   x-2 \\ 
           3x &  -2  &  2x-4
\end{array}
\right| = 0
$$
What I did was to rewrite second column -2 5 -2 and the third 3x-6 x-2  2x-4.
Then I multiplie x*5*(2x-4))+(-2*(x-2)*-2)+((3x-6)*5((2x-4)- (3x * 5 * 3x-6 )-(-2*(x-2)*(-2))-(2x-4)*5*(3x-6)) and I find 2. Is right this method;

Comment: I think he's doing gaussian elimination but this is indeed unreadable. @amajon heyp Format your question appropriately with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @amanjonheyp What even is the question?

Comment: Ι cant guys . I dont know how to format it . I am from phone. May that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By noticing that you have multiples of $x$ in the first column and multiples of $(x-2)$ in the third column you can simplify the determinant like this:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
  x &-2 &3x-6 \\
 -x & 5 & x-2 \\
 3x &-2 &2x-4\\
\end{vmatrix}=
x(x-2)\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-2 & 3 \\
 -1 & 5 & 1 \\
  3 &-2 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
This should make the problem easier.

Comment: I didn't do this. My is right; what I found was 2

Comment: $x=0$ is a root, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)